# Managing XenServer and its Virtual Machines Remotely

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, citrix

I have a dedicated server in a data center and I want to install XenServer for virtualization.

XenServer will be running 2 or 3 virtual servers, all of which will be using Public IP's along with a remotely accessible SSH tunnel.

I want to know how I can manage the XenServer virtual machines, such as rebooting, installing Operating Systems etc with a GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't really a XenServer specific question. XenServer comes with XenCenter which is its GUI management tool, but how you connect to your server is completely situation dependent. XenCenter connects directly to XenServer using its management IP, but you certainly wouldn't want a public facing IP. A VPN would be ideal for this, but again, it all depends on what facilities you have at your data center.

Comment: can i download and install xen centre on my remote server is this possible?

Comment: @user133916 Well, you can install it onto a Virtual Machine, sure. It's not really a very good idea, though, because what do you do if that machine goes down - seeing as you only have one server. It would be okay for day to day management, though.

The bigger question is how you're going to build this in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

There are two approaches to managing XenServer that don't involve adding any extra tools.

1. Command line interface (CLI).  If you ssh to XenServer, you'll be logged into the Dom0 VM's shell.  Here you can manage XenServer using the `xe` command.  E.g. `xe vm-list` will return details of the VMs.  `xe` has auto complete, so if follow `xe` with a space and press the autocomplete (usually a tabe) tab, you'll be offered a list of the available commmands.
2. Windows-based GUI.  Point your browser at the XenServer.  This will give you access to the XenCenter installer.  Download, run.  You can connect to your XenCenter, see the VMs, access their console, and start/stop them.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a shopping question in a way but I have recently started using [Cloudstack](http://cloudstack.org/) and it is perfect for of-site management, creating new VM's, shutting down, SSH, free HA, etc.

It also good for allowing other Staff members limited access to do this.

However as a warning, this is open source software and the user base is limited. The documentation is extremely poor and the support is next to none, so be prepared to get extremely frustrated, however, once you get it working, it is very good.

There are of course a number of other options offering simular services for Xen Web GUI management such as [Open Stack](http://www.openstack.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Install and configure a windows xp vm which will run the XenCenter software. Remote Desktop into this vm and you will have full control